# my laptops Mac address does not show up in Active Wireless Client Table

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I'm connected to D link Dir-615 router wirelessly and the my mac address does not show up in Active Wireless Client Table and also it shows  " connected with no internet " .
There are other devices that are connected (5) and their mac address's are also shown in Active Wireless Client Table unlike mine. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: How are you "connected"? You would be connected if you were getting webpages after associating with the network. Your MAC address needs to be in the Client table to participate on a network. You must not be connected. Do you get errors?